# get user's rank by points and registration date in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

How to get the users rank using it's points and registration time ? i have tried to get users by same criteria and it's working fine.

```
  await User.find({
      sort: {
          rewardPoints: 0,
          createdAt: 1
      }   
  }).limit(limit);
```

Now i want to get my rank only but it is not giving me correct result's by this code

```
 await User.count({ 
     createdAt: { "<" : user.createdAt },
     rewardPoints: { ">=": user.rewardPoints },
  });
```

Comment: You switched to a `.count` instead of `.find` in your second query. That's only right if you want to know how many users match the criteria (not get the records of matching users). Based on the sql in your self-answer I'd guess that may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was finally did it using a sql query:

```
SELECT id
          , firstName
          , rank
          FROM ( 
            SELECT 
            *
            , (@rank := @rank + 1) AS rank
            FROM 
            user
            CROSS JOIN( 
            SELECT
              @rank := 0
            )  
            AS 
              init_var_var
            ORDER BY
            user.rewardPoints DESC,
            user.createdAt ASC    
            )
          AS logins_ordered_ranked
          WHERE
            id = "${user.id}"
```